# Как сделать чтобы при перезагрузке страницы открывалась последняя активная вкладка?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Нужна помощь в решении задачки. Есть табы:

```
<div class="tabs">
        <ul class="tabs-switchers">
            <li class="tabs-switcher active">Первая вкладка</li>
      <li class="tabs-switcher">Вторая вкладка</li>
            <li class="tabs-switcher">Третья вкладка</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tabs-item active">
    Содержимое первой вкладки
    </div>

   <div class="tabs-item">
    Содержимое второй вкладки
    </div>
    <div class="tabs-item">
    Содержимое третьей вкладки
    </div>
    </div>
<script>
var $doc = $(document);
$doc.on('click', '.tabs-switcher:not(.active):not(.disabled)', function(e) {
        var $thisTab = $(this),
            $tabContent = $thisTab.closest('.tabs').find('.tabs-item'),
            $thisTabContent = $tabContent.eq($thisTab.index());
        $thisTab
            .addClass('active')
            .siblings().removeClass('active');
        $tabContent.removeClass('active');
        $thisTabContent.addClass('active');
        $thisTab.trigger('tabClick', $thisTabContent);
    })
</script>
```

Рабочий пример тут: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/36879/

Нужно сделать чтобы при перезагрузке страницы открывалась не первая вкладка, как сейчас, а та, которую пользователь открыл последней перед перезагрузкой страницы. Если я правильно понял копать надо в сторону localStorage? Подскажите, как решить эту задачку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например можно так сделать. Но это с учетом того, что такие вкладки у вас в одном экземпляре на странице.

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/37747/

```
var $doc = $(document);
$doc.on('click', '.tabs-switcher:not(.active):not(.disabled)', function(e) {
        var $thisTab = $(this),
            $tabContent = $thisTab.closest('.tabs').find('.tabs-item'),
            $thisTabContent = $tabContent.eq($thisTab.index());
        $thisTab
            .addClass('active')
            .siblings().removeClass('active');
        $tabContent.removeClass('active');
        $thisTabContent.addClass('active');
        $thisTab.trigger('tabClick', $thisTabContent);
    //сохраняем номер вкладки
    localStorage.tabIndex=$thisTab.index();
    })

  //при загрузке страницы читаем значение из Localstorage
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    var x=localStorage.tabIndex;
    if (x) {
      var $thisTab=$('.tabs-switchers .tabs-switcher').eq(x),
        $tabContent = $thisTab.closest('.tabs').find('.tabs-item'),
        $thisTabContent = $tabContent.eq($thisTab.index());
      $thisTab
        .addClass('active')
        .siblings().removeClass('active');
      $tabContent.removeClass('active');
      $thisTabContent.addClass('active');
      $thisTab.trigger('tabClick', $thisTabContent);
    }
});
```